# Как в шейдере использовать второй канал UV?

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

На данный момент шейдер выглядит вот так:

```
Shader "Map/RoadUV" {
  Properties {
    _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _NoiseTex ("Albedo noise (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
  }
  SubShader {
    Tags {
      "RenderType"="Opaque"
      "Queue" = "Geometry+1"
    }
    LOD 200
    Offset -1, -1

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows decal:blend
    #pragma target 3.0

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    sampler2D _NoiseTex;

    struct Input {
      float2 uv_MainTex;
      float3 worldPos;
    };

    half _Glossiness;
    half _Metallic;
    fixed4 _Color;

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
      float4 noise = tex2D(_NoiseTex, IN.worldPos.xz * 0.025);
      fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.worldPos.xz * 0.025);
      float blend = IN.uv_MainTex.x;
      blend *= noise.x + 0.5;
      blend = smoothstep(0.4, 0.7, blend);

      o.Albedo = c.rgb;
      o.Metallic = _Metallic;
      o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
      o.Alpha = blend;
    }
    ENDCG
  }
  FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Мне нужно вместо `worldPos` что бы использовался второй UV

Comment: Вы что-то делаете совсем не то, или я не понял зачем это

Comment: зачем мировые координаты использовать как текстурные, не пойму

Comment: @StrangerintheQ для плоского объекта это довольно таки удобно, но сейчас мне нужно как раз таки поменять c worldPos на UV

Comment: это будет работать только для неподвижных объектов, ну да ладно, не понятно в в чем проблема, какого эффекта вы пытаетесь добиться? Вы приводите код шейдера который что-то делает, без объяснений...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я прекрастно понимаю что данный пример будет работать только при статических обьектах, поэтому я и хочу его переделать, что бы координаты брались с UV, а не с глобальных координат, об этом вопрос, как извлечь именно UV координаты второго канала

Comment: ок, а а а каком втором канале идет речь?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-uv2.html

Comment: для этого надо написать в вершинном шейдере перенос этих координат из атрибутов вершины на выход шейдера по аналогии с  `o.uv_MainTex = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord.xy , _MainTex);`, и потом использовать во фрагментном шейдере, если Вам до вечера не ответят, я попробую собрать пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось у меня наколдовать, в общем теперь код выглядит вот так вот:

```
  Shader "Map/RoadUV" {
    Properties {
      _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
      _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
      _NoiseTex ("Albedo noise (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
      _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
      _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    }
    SubShader {
      Tags {
        "RenderType"="Opaque"
        "Queue" = "Geometry+1"
      }
      LOD 200
      Offset -1, -1

      CGPROGRAM
      #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows decal:blend vertex:vert
      #pragma target 3.5

      sampler2D _MainTex;
      sampler2D _NoiseTex;

      struct Input {
        float2 uv_MainTex : TEXCOORD0;
        float3 myUV2;
      };

      half _Glossiness;
      half _Metallic;
      fixed4 _Color;

      void vert (inout appdata_full v, out Input data) {
        UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input, data);
        data.myUV2 = v.texcoord2.xyz;
      }

      void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
        float4 noise = tex2D(_NoiseTex, IN.myUV2.xy * 0.025);
        fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.myUV2.xy * 0.025);
        float blend = IN.uv_MainTex.x;
        blend *= noise.x + 0.5;
        blend = smoothstep(0.4, 0.7, blend);

        o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        o.Metallic = _Metallic;
        o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
        o.Alpha = blend;
      }
      ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
  }
```